# How do I make this sentence grammatically correct?

Tags: grammaticality, tenses

> As this week’s lesson comes to an end, we have now completed both Unit One and Two, a perfect time to reflect on what we have learned.

I think there is something wrong with the tense here, but I'm not sure how to fix it.

Comment: What do you think is wrong?  The worst I see is that it probably should be "Units".

Comment: @Hot Licks I think it’s because it’s talking about a future progressive event “comes to an end” and “have now completed”. I think “we will have completed both...” sounds better to my native ears...: “As this week’s lesson comes to an end, ***we will have completed*** both Unit one and two, a perfect time to reflect on what we have learned”.

Comment: @aesking - But we have already completed both.

Comment: @Hot Licks “As... ***comes to*** an end” is a future progressive because it *hasn’t ended* yet. It is *about* to end. Think of tense as being on a scale rather than “complete”/“incomplete” or “start”/“end”.

Comment: @aesking -- We completed units 1 & 2 and are halfway through unit 3.

Comment: @Hot Licks I believe this is because of the usage of the *as* being used as a conjunction to mean ((as if)) e.g. He looks ***as he had seen*** a ghost. [Merriam Webster, entry 2](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/as). In the previous sentence it doesn’t mean he had seen a ghost. But as if he had. I believe *as* is playing a similar role here, a conditional sentence along the lines of: “upon completion...we will have...” or sometimes as in Merriam Webster’s example to make a stark contrast between two things.

Comment: @aesking - Are you serious?  "As" is being used as a simple preposition.  It is not being used with the meaning "as if'.

Comment: @Hot Licks *as* has many uses it can be used as a conjunction. So unless you have any grammatical knowledge or expertise that can refute it not, then say, I won’t accept it’s a preposition just because of “I say so; so it is!”

Comment: @aesking -- But "As if this week's lesson comes to an end" is gibberish.

Comment: @Hot Licks “He looks as he had seen a ghost” looks gibberish at first glance too, until you understand the meaning. That is, as you should know by now, language can be figurative or literal. Why do you think “as if” wasn’t included in the example sentence and only under the dictionary meaning? Because it is a *meaning*. It’s not meant to be included in the sentence...

Comment: (...) also I already explained the function of “as” already, it is acting like a conditional...but you just profusely refused and said it was a preposition without any evidence.

Comment: @aesking -- The use of "as" quoted by MW is archaic.  And if the intended meaning were "as if" then the sentence would presumably make more sense with "as if" substituted, not less.

Comment: You do know “as if” can be expressed in more than one ways, yet you ignore it. “as if” was expressed in MW’s sentence without actually using ”as if”, IT is a meaning for a conditional situation. I will be more clearer... figurative or idiomatic language certainly isn’t archaic and it isn’t direct. “As if” is a general conditional statement which can include, and this condition doesn’t have to be expressed directly as “as if” but it can be translated along the lines of ‘IF this were to happen...’ and hence: <s> as </s> *if this week’s lessons comes to an end, we will have completed...*

Comment: Don’t you understand? “*He looks as <s> if </s> he had seen a ghost*” Most people could interpret *as* as *because*, but the meaning is *as if*.

Comment: I place emphasis on *meaning*.

Comment: @aesking - But the OP doesn't mention a ghost!!!

Comment: There is nothing ungrammatical about the sentence, so long as it is parsed in the correct way. The problem is that it has an ambiguous meaning; if interpreted in a different way, then it becomes ungrammatical. But there is no way of saying for certain which interpretation is correct.

Answer (score -1):

Your instinct is correct.

In addition to Hot Licks' comment, the sentence doesn't make sense. 
It is a little more obvious when you omit the parenthetical: "As this week's lesson comes to an end a perfect time to reflect on what we have learned."

How about one of these two options:

- It is a perfect time to reflect on the first two units we covered in this week's lesson.
- As this week's lesson comes to an end, we have completed the first two units and it is a perfect time to reflect on what we have learned.